# iOS App Distribution Invalid Binary

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit a new update of my app. I upload it via Xcode's built in uploader. It gets successfully uploaded to the store however it say's processing and then I get a notification saying

```
Your app AppName, 3.1.1 (9) (Apple ID: 1234567890) has changed Invalid Binary.
```

That is all I'm getting.  Not receiving any emails on why it changed. Looked through a lot of stuff online and people are suggesting that my app doesn't have all the correct permissions. New with this update is my inclusion of an in-app purchase but other than that that's it.

I know this is so vague and I'm so confused why it won't upload.

Comment: "My app has an in-app purchase" And is that new in this version?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me several months ago, and it was because of bad metadata.  I had forgotten to increment the build number when I uploaded an update.  But I vaguely remember that when my "invalid binary" email came in it said exactly what was wrong. Have you looked in iTunes Connect to see if there's any helpful information there?